# Enable Jump Frame

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a powershell script to enable Jumpframe on Openstack windows VM's. The command to find active network card and also the current MTU value also the command to change MTU value all below.

From the below command I am first finding the active network card , then trying to find the MTU value of that NIC and if I found MTU value less than 1600 I need that to be changed to 9000.

```
PS C:\> **wmic nic where "netconnectionid like '%'" get netconnectionid**
NetConnectionID
Ethernet

PS C:\> **netsh.exe int ipv4 show subint**

   MTU  MediaSenseState   Bytes In  Bytes Out  Interface
------  ---------------  ---------  ---------  -------------
4294967295                1          0       1400  Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
  1200                1  1335974344    5867793  Ethernet

PS C:\> **netsh int ipv4 set subint "Ethernet" mtu=9000 store=persistent**
```

Can anyone let me know how can I write a condition to accomplish what I am looking for ?

Comment: Try Get-NetAdapter with the -Name paramter

Comment: You can use `Get-NetIPInterface |? {$_.NlMtu -lt 1600}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$enabledAdaptersNames = Get-NetAdapter |? {$_.status -eq "Up" -or $_.status -eq "Disconnected"} | Select -ExpandProperty name

Get-NetIPInterface |? { $enabledAdapterNames -contains $_.InterfaceAlias -and $_.NlMtu -lt 1600} |  Set-NetIPInterface -NlMtuBytes 9000
```

Comment: Get-NetAdapter  and Set-NetIPInterface command is not working as I am running this command on KVM based windows VM's.

Comment: I am able to use the  methord which you have shared with my commands.